# (shorter) exact sequences

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

Consider two sequences $A\overset{f}\to B\to C\to0$ and $0\to A\to B\overset g\to C$ of abelian groups.

The first one is exact iff $C\cong\operatorname{coker}f$ as a consequence of the first isomorphism theorem.

But why do we have that the second is exact iff $A\cong\ker g$ ?

Comment: Neither of those statements are true. Just isomorphism isn't enough for exactness. For instance, take $A = C = \Bbb Z$ and $B = \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ where $f(a) = (a,0)$ and $g(a, b) = a$. Then all your isomorphisms hold, but the sequences aren't exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one direction is true.  Suppose your second sequence is exact.  The image of $A \to B$ must be iso to $A$ since that map has trivial kernel.  But this image is the kernel of $g$ by exactness.  The converse is false.